# If Custom field is something, then add a class to a div

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I have a custom field in Wordpress of wilcity_belongs_to with a value of 21956. I am trying to get my php code to work, so that if the custom field's value is 21956 then it will run the Jquery code and add the class .hidden to a specific Div.

I do not get any errors running this code, although i do not see it echoing the Jquery either. What am i missing? Thanks

**Updated Script so far:**

```
global $post;
$meta_print_value = get_post_meta($post->ID,'wilcity_belongs_to',true);
if( $meta_print_value == '21956' ) {
    echo "
<script type=\"text/javascript\">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.wil-single-navimage1646724156466').addClass('hidden');
}
</script>
";
} else {
    
}
```

This is the custom field i am trying to refer to:
[Custom Field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zErc0.png)

Comment: try this one 
if (21956==$wilcity_belongs_to)

Comment: @JahidHasan type would only matter, if this was using `===` as comparison operator.

Comment: So where does the variable `$wilcity_belongs_to` actually gets is value assigned? Have you verified what it contains in this place by making a debug output (`var_dump`) at least?

Comment: @Cbroe so wilcity_belongs_to get its value assigned from a listing plan, if they choose a specific listing plan the meta value would be 21956 for one and another value for another plan etc. Not sure how to do a (var_dump) though

Comment: `var_dump($wilcity_belongs_to);`

Comment: _"so wilcity_belongs_to get its value assigned from a listing plan"_ - I did not ask about your custom _field_, I asked about this particular variable. You are aware that those are not automatically the same thing, right?

Comment: Sorry @CBroe im still quite new at all this, and trying to figure it all out. The code above is of numerous forums that i put together as that is the only one that makes sense to me as i have minimal coding experience in PHP and Jquery.

Comment: @CBroe this is what i got from the debug:
Notice: Undefined variable: wilcity_belongs_to in ***/functions.php on line 17

Comment: So you simply assumed just because you created some custom fields, all those values would automatically get put in variables of the same name ...? Nope. Assuming your are talking about the popular ACF (advanced custom fields) plugin here: https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_field/

Answer (score 0):

this probably happens because the moment the script is appended to the DOM the element with class `.wil-single-navimage1646724156466` is not even present either because you still need to echo it or because the element in the document isn't ready yet

you need to wait until the element is present in the DOM then execute the jQuery code, this is usually done with `$((function(){...})` that basically waits for the whole document to be ready before the content of the function is executed

Comment: I am guessing that _"although i do not see it echoing the Jquery either"_ meant the whole script element doesn't even show up in the output to begin with.

Comment: Sorry, yes that is what i mean